# When I use opendns servers in my dir-655, inranet addresses don't get resolved anymore

Tags: router, dns, opendns, dir-655

When I use opendns servers in my dir-655, inranet addresses don't get resolved anymore.
Is there a setting somewhere to tell it to ignore opendns for internal dns requests?
Perhaps this is a commonly known pitfall of using openDNS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have a similar issue with a DIR-615. only solution i found was to replace the system name in the URL with the IP address of the server. not really the ideal solution perhaps

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've been doing as well :-)